# php execute command tcpdump

Tags: php, shellexecute, tcpdump

I know to execute the command should be root, and I find the popen() in php maybe help me to do it. But my code does not work, I do not know the reason......

My code is:

```
    $sucommand = "su --login root -c tcpdump -c 20000 -s 0 -w $filename &";
    $rootpasswd = "password";
    $fp = @popen($sucommand,"w");
    @fputs($fp,$rootpasswd);
    @pclose($fp);
```

Is something I typed wrong?

My php file is in Linux server, and I change all file owner in the directory to apache (and mode 0777).

Add:
If I should use sudo, what should I concerned? I use php coding.

Any suggestion appreciated!

Comment: `su` is going to be expecting a newline after the password (after all, you have to press Return after typing your password interactively).

Comment: I found it to be easier to use `sudo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sudo` with `-S` option to pass password from command line itself.

```
[suku@suku-ld ~]$ echo 'YOURSUDOPASSWORD' | sudo -S tcpdump -c 20000 -i eth1 -s 0 -w tmp
tcpdump: listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
```

**[ADDED]** : How to add a user to sudores list?

```
suku@ubuntu-vm:~$ which tcpdump 
/usr/sbin/tcpdump
```

Execute the command `visudo` and enter either of following:

```
apache  ALL=/usr/sbin/tcpdump
apache  ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/tcpdump
```

If you use the first one, then when you execute the script with sudo command, it will prompt for apache user's password. But with the second one, it will not even prompt for a sudo password.

Note: I recommend the first one to use.

Note : I am assuming you are running your web server with the user apache. If not, change the user name accordingly.

Comment: You probably know this, but in case the asker doesn't, it would be a better idea to put the password in a file and pipe the file into sudo.  That prevents the password from being displayed in the running process list.  Assuming the file is properly secured, it's *reasonably* secure, though storing a password in a file in plain text is still a questionable idea.  +1

Comment: Corbin, yes, your are right. For added security, we can store encrypted password in a file and then decrypte value using some php functions inside script to pipe into `sudo`

Comment: Thanks for your answering, and I will be care of security.
But I use .php to execute the command, any priority or owner concerned?
I am confused the password is for root or apache?

Comment: Guys, if you decode the pass from the file inside the PHP and then pipe in to the command line, wouldn't it still show up in the process list?

Comment: So, is it possible to use PHP to do tcpdump command?
I use bourne shell script to do it before... And I try to translate it to PHP code......
In cgi file, I do not face this problem( do not need root mode).

I am not sure the real problem is about the authority or owner or coding or other reason......

Answer (score 1):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell (as root if requested), it solves the limitations of exec() and shell_exec(). Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
$timeout = 3600000; // how many miliseconds will it take to capture 20000 packets?
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd('tcpdump -c 20000 -i eth1 -s 0 -w /tmp/tmp.pcap', false, $timeout);
//the return will be a string containing the return of the command
echo $return1;
```

Then pick up the /tmp/tmp.pcap for processing.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing!
I'll try it later!